# How to implement basic authentication in Spring boot?

Tags: java, angularjs, spring-security, spring-boot

I've followed [this](https://spring.io/blog/2015/01/12/spring-and-angular-js-a-secure-single-page-application) and [this](https://spring.io/blog/2015/01/12/the-login-page-angular-js-and-spring-security-part-ii) tutorial to create a skeleton of an Angular.JS application with a Java-based backend. Its code can be found [here](https://github.com/dsyer/spring-security-angular/tree/master/single).

It has authentication - at the start Spring boot writes to the console a random password, which you can use to login to the started application. User name is `user` and the password is printed in the console at the start:

[image: Console output]

Now I want to have several user accounts with fixed passwords (it's OK, if they are hardcoded).

How can I do this in that application without breaking compatibility with AngularJS?

I suppose that I have to modify `SecurityConfiguration` in [UiApplication](https://github.com/dsyer/spring-security-angular/blob/master/single/src/main/java/demo/UiApplication.java) and use something like

```
@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
        .withUser("user")
        .password("password")
        .roles("USER");
}
```

as explained [here](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.2.3.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/builders/HttpSecurity.html), but I'm not sure that it won't break AngularJS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the solution:

```
@Configuration
@Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)
class SecurityConfiguration extends
    WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


    @Autowired
    public void registerAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("user1")
            .password("password1")
            .roles("ADMIN")
            .and()
            .withUser("user2")
            .password("password2")
            .roles("USER");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as you don't change the authentication scheme (i.e. BASIC, FORM etc.), AngularJS doesn't care about how you manage the user accounts in the backend. Of course if you would have used a fixed user and password and have it hardcoded in the AngularJS code, you would have to change this.

Answer (score 0):

It wouldn't break the angular compatibility. But in addition to the code change you mentioned, you would also need to make sure that you are allowing access to /login URI anonymously. Change in your overloaded configure method would also be required, something as follows:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
  http
    .httpBasic()
  .and()
    .authorizeRequests()
      .antMatchers("/login.html").permitAll()
  .antMatchers("/index.html", "/home.html").authenticated()
      .antMatchers("/index.html", "/home.html").hasRole("USER")
      .anyRequest().authenticated();
}
```